# Formview not letting me add a second record after adding a first

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource, formview, autopostback

I have a FormView which allows inserting of records into a table, and then also sends out a confirmation email that a record has been added. The email is supposed to go a particular set of users, based on a department selected. So I have the below. All works well, except after I add a record, and the email sends, and then it takes me back, and when I click the Add new record button again I get '***Could not find control 'formViewNewItem$ddlInsertDepartment' in ControlParameter 'RoleID'.***' It's like the formView is staying in insertmode or something after a record is inserted into the table.

**Data source for emails to be sent:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsourceToEmails" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Email] + ',' FROM [Users] WHERE [Role] = @RoleID FOR XML PATH ('')">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**FormView code:**

```
<asp:FormView ID="formViewNewItem" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Test_ID" 
        DataSourceID="testDataSource" OnDataBound="formViewNewItem_DataBound" 
                OnItemInserted="testRecord_Inserted">
        <InsertItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInsertDepartment" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
          <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>Accounting</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>Marketing</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>Programming</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewRecord" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
            CommandName="New" Font-Bold="True" Text="Add New" 
            onclick="btnAddNewRecord_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

**Page Load (only create parameter for email if in insert mode)**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (formViewNewItem.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
        {
            // Create your ControlParameter
            ControlParameter deptParam = new ControlParameter();
            deptParam.ControlID = formViewNewItem.FindControl("ddlInsertDepartment").UniqueID;
            deptParam.PropertyName = "SelectedValue";
            deptParam.Name = "RoleID";
            deptParam.Type = TypeCode.String;
            // Add it to your SelectParameters collection
            dsourceToEmails.SelectParameters.Add(deptParam);
        }
```

**OnInserted, once record is successfully added, send email:**

```
    protected void testRecord_Inserted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView dvToEmails = (DataView)dsourceToEmails.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            string emailsTo = (string)dvToEmails.Table.Rows[0][0];
            emailsTo = emailsTo.TrimEnd(',');

            string networkUserName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
            string emailUserName = networkUserName.Substring(12);

            DropDownList departmentSelection = (DropDownList)formViewNewItem.FindControl("ddlInsertDepartment");

            var message = new MailMessage();
            var client = new SmtpClient();

            message.From = new MailAddress("test@abc.com", "Task Tracker");
            message.To.Add(emailsTo);
            message.Subject = "New Project assigned for " + departmentSelection.SelectedValue;
            message.Body = "A new task has been assigned.
<br /><br /><b>Entered by:</b> " + emailUserName;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            client.Send(message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer to this...I had to move the SqlDataSource to the InsertItemTemplate, and then use the FindControl method in the OnInserted code to find the SqlDataSource that I had moved, but all worked as it should after all of that.